# how to get string like " My message ("sent")"

Tags: javascript

I defined a variable and get an output which solved the problem (as following)

```
javascript
var s = "My Message ("sent")";
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use other quotation marks.

```js
var s = 'My Message ("sent")'; console.log(s);
```

Or you can use character escaping

```js
var s = "My Message (\"sent\")"; console.log(s);
```